# Backbone.js why isn't the DOM available in render function?

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js, render

In the render function of backbone,

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html('<div id="customID"></div>

    console.log($('#customID')[0]);
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log($('#customID')[0]);
    }, 1);
}
```

the first console.log returns "undefined"...

the second one returns a DOM node.

Why isn't the DOM available in the render function without a timeout?

Comment: When/how is `this.el` being added to the dom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the element hasn't been added to the document yet. The DOM is available, but the element isn't in it.

The `setTimeout` call makes the browser call the code when it's not busy running code any more, and that happens when the rendering is complete and the element has been added to the document.

If you use the element as scope in the jQuery call, it will find the div eventhough it's not in the document:

```
console.log($('#customID', this.$el)[0]);
```

or:

```
console.log(this.$el.find('#customID')[0]);
```

Comment: Are you not supposed to try to do this in backbone? What is the proper backbone way to do this?  Add a callback?  I ran into this from not knowing where to attach a .datepicker method to a dom element in the render function.  I was basically attaching the function to nothing since the element wasn't added to the document yet.

Comment: You do as Mu suggests - use this.$(...).  this.$ refers to the document fragment.

Comment: @EdwardMSmith: Correction: `this.$` is a function that uses the document fragment as scope for a jQuery call. `this.el` refers to the document fragment, and `this.$el` refers to a jQuery object containing the document fragment. Either can be used to find an element within the document fragment.

Comment: @natecraft1: The rendering model of backbone doesn't make it easy to apply anything to the elements after they have been added to the document. For most uses you can locate the element inside the element created for the view, but if you need it to be added to the document first (for example if it needs to be reflowed first), you need to use a workaround like a timeout.